# How do I throw a boomerang or spear in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've recently come into possession of a lovely boomerang.

[image]

Its description says something about how wonderfully it returns to one when thrown, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to throw it.

It's in the melee weapons part of the inventory, and functions like one: when you press Y, you just swing it like a stick.

The same is true of spears: some of their descriptions go on about how well weighted they are for throwing... but there doesn't seem to be any way to throw em.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Careful what you wish for - [an Australian aborigine who just bought a new boomerang will spend the rest of his life trying to get rid of the previous one](https://youtu.be/yxdCIf91mcQ?t=4m13s)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can throw any weapon by holding down and releasing the upper right shoulder button (<kbd>R</kbd>). A thrown weapon will deal double it's base damage and stagger most enemies.

[**Source on double damage**](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/4vnktj/breath_of_the_wild_heres_a_list_of_40_tips_and/):

> **Critical Hits** – Weapons that you have no use for are perfect for throwing at monsters. If one hits, it will deal double damage.

Keep in mind that throwing a weapon will take away a lot of it's durability, sometimes destroying it instantly.

Boomerangs fly back to you when thrown but you still have to catch them manually by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in the correct moment.

Throwing a normal weapon is usually a good idea if there's only one hit left.

Comment: @Seiyria The loading screen remark is just a tip to get extra damage out of your weapon. If it's about to break anyway, you might as well get some more damage out of it.

Comment: I found this out when I accidentally threw my first axe (only weapon at the time) off a cliff.

Answer (score 4):

While your weapon is drawn, hold down the R button, the release it when aimed where you want to hit. This can be done with any weapon, not just spears and boomerangs.

When the boomerangs returns to you, you need to press A to actually grab it, otherwise it will simply go past you.

Comment: Isn't it "R" not "ZR" to throw?

Comment: @BlueBarren Damn Nintendo with their button naming scheme. It'd be RB on any other controller, and the trigger would generally be R, but Nintendo have to switch it around.

Comment: actually it's RB and RT on Xbox and R1 and R2 on Playstation sooo ;P

Comment: Not only that, but Nintendo has been using L/R and ZL/ZR for years now. This is not new to the Switch.

Comment: It's been this way since they released [the classic controller](http://www.smashbros.com/wii/en_uk/gamemode/various/images/various14/various14_071126e-l.jpg) on the Wii.

Comment: @sgroves The naming convention does seem a bit odd. Usually the "z" buttons are fairly small buttons that aren't frequently used.  For some reason the z buttons are huge compared to the regular R and L's.  As someone whose last Nintendo console was a Gamecube, it's _extremely_ confusing since the Z button on GC was where the R button is now, and the Z-R and Z-L buttons would have been L and R on GC.

Answer (score -1):

Push the shoulder button R. Be prepared to catch it when it comes back using the A button. Just some advice: Hitting anything causes major damage to the enemy the boomerang hits.